# Why does Coldfusion strip out zeros in list function

Tags: coldfusion, delimiter, coldfusion-10

I've run into a strange behavior with Coldfusion 10- I have a variable named `myString`, "12600A07xxx".

I want the substrings before and after "A07", so I use "A07" as a list delimiter, and type `listFirst(myString, "A07")` and `listLast(myString, "A07")`.

For the first, it's stripping out the zeros, and returning "126" when it should be returning "12600". It does the same with `ListGetAt()`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

I see - CF is treating "A07" as three different delimiters, "A", "0", and "7", instead of a single delimiter, "A07". And there a couple of ways to deal with this, the simplest being to temporarily substitute "A07" with a single character such as a pipe and use that as the temporary delimiter.

Comment: Per the docs `A string or a variable that contains one. ColdFusion treats each character in the string as a delimiter. The default value is comma.`

Answer (score 5):

As you already noticed, ColdFusion has many functions with single character delimiters. However, there are also functions that support multi-character delimiters, e.g.
`listToArray( list [, delimiters[, includeEmptyFields[, multiCharacterDelimiter]]] )`.

Example:

```
parts = listToArray("12600A07xxx", "A07", false, true);
writeOutput( parts[1] ); // >> 12600
writeOutput( parts[2] ); // >> xxx
```

*On a side note: Are you sure you want to split the input using a specific delimiter? You might be better off using regular expression patterns with this kind of data. Just a guess though.*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to use `reReplaceNoCase()`. Like this:

```
theString = "12600A07xxx";
prefix  =  reReplaceNoCase(theString , "A07.*", "");
suffix  =  reReplaceNoCase(theString , ".*A07", "");
```